# Add new feature to existing classes (C#)

Tags: c#, oop

In a c#.net application I have a two classes as below

> **Employee**
>
> EmployeeId : int : *Primary key*
>
> Name : string
>
> **Job**
>
> JobId : int : *Primary key*
>
> Name : string
>
> EmployeeId : int

In database (SQL Server) I have two tables to save data from those classes (Employee & Job)
(ID fields are auto increment fields so can have same no in both tables)

Now I need to implement a new feature to give users to add comments for Employees or for Jobs, So I need to create a single Comment class to share by both classes.

What is the best Class & Table Structure to implement this new feature.

Comment: Could you not create a base class and then have the Employee and Job classes inherit from it?

Comment: @Daniel That will be good, but If I do so how should I create the tables to save comments? Two separate tables or one common table? and how to link those tables with existing tables?

Comment: How are you accessing your data? (Linq-to-Sql, etc.)

Comment: @Filburt I use only simple SQL queries, Is there any advantage if i use Linq-to-SQL (or EntityFramework) in this scenario?

Comment: @Nalaka526 It is mostly different in that they will take care of a lot of boilerplate code and plumbing for your CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend a database design like which allows adding more comment types in the future without the need to modify your database.

**Table Comment**

```
Id (int, Primary Key)
CommenteeId (int, not null)
CommentTypeId (int, not null)
Text (nvarchar(255))
```

**Table CommentType**

```
Id (int, Primary Key)
Name (nvarchar(50), not null)
```

`CommenteeId` will reference `Job` or `Employee` or any other table you'd need to comment in the future.

`CommentTypeId` will reference `CommentType` where you can add types as needed.

---

As for your class design it could look like this:

```
public class Job
{
    public List<Comment> Comments;
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Employee
{
    public List<Comment> Comments;
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

... as a basic idea. How and when your `Comment` is loaded as part of `Employee` or `Job` is depending on your method of accessing your database.

Comment: Is it ok to use this table structure if I create comments base class and then have the Employee and Job classes inherit from it?

Comment: @Nalaka526 You wouldn't need `Employee` and `Job` inherting from a comments base class - Comments would be a (private) member and your classes would just expose the `Text` as a property.

Comment: Wouldn't this break the ability to add more than one comment to a Job or a Employee?

Comment: @Nalaka526 Having more than one comment only requires a little change to the class design - I confess I missed the plural in your question.

Comment: If I use this method, even though I can create new comment type easily but it needs to hardcode the CommentTypeId in their respective classes (Employee or Job)?

Comment: @Nalaka526 I tend to use Enumerations for this, but yes you'd have typed Comments in your respective classes. If you wanted to take extensibility further, you could think about an ICommentable interface.

Answer (score 3):

You could create the following tables...

> Comment (CommentId, Text, [other fields...])
>
> JobComments (CommentId, JobId)
>
> EmployeeComments (CommentId, EmployeeId)

.. and then you could use either table per type inheritance (if using EF see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc765425.aspx)) or you can do it with standard relationships.

Comment: I think this is the best method if I create a base class for comments and inherit it by Employee & Job, right?

Comment: @Nalaka526 I think that's definitely the best way to go as it will also allow for future extension

Answer (score 1):

If there is no differnece between Comments for Jobs and Employees i would suggesst next:

1. Add Table "Comment". I am not sure about your business logic, but it would have next filds i suppose:
   CommentdId, UserId, IsJobComment ( this will be bit value which will show difference between cmmments for job or employee), IsEmployeeComment ( will show if this is comment for Employee ), Text, RelatedItemID( this will contain id of the related job or employee )
2. Class structure:
   Add List to classes Job and Employee
3. Add object comment with values: ID, UserID, Text.

**Update: One more idea.**

Instead of adding IsEmployeeComment and IsJobComment change this to simple column CommentTypeID.

Then add Table CommentsType which will have next fields:
1.CommentTypeID
2.CommentType - string value which will define type: Employee or Job. So, when new comment type added: just add value to this field.

Comment: yeah. Actually in this case it can be done next way: relatedItemID can be separated to: EmployeeID, and JobID, with default value Null. In case new type of the comment will be added - then new column added.

Comment: @dimko1 Adding CommentTypeID will make it really flexible, I think

Comment: @Nalaka526 that not just adding type, but adding one more table. Make sure that this is ok for you.

Comment: The problem with a "CommentType" approach is that it can lead to orphaned data as there is no referential integrity (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).

Comment: Not sure that comment type will be a dictionary which will not change a lot of times. And this is more most flexible approach i think:)

Answer (score 1):

Database-wise I would prefer not to need a separate table for each type of comment.

For instance the Employees and Jobs tables could have a CommentID column, and the Comments table would have something like this:

```
CommentID int
RelatedCommentID int
CommentText ntext
```

Then you would set RelatedCommentID=CommentID for the first and all following comments.

Comment: This will make it bit hard to retrieve comments for a specific Employee (or Job), right?

Comment: Not at all: Select e.EmployeeID, c.CommentText From Employees e Left Join Comments c On e.CommentID=c.RelatedCommentID

Answer (score 0):

For this it is better to create two tables: JobComments and EmployeComments.

Content for both is the same:

> CommentId : int : Primary key & auto_increment
>
> ReferenceId : int : Foreign key
>
> Content : varchar

Maybe you need some more fields, based on your needs.

Comment: And in the future you'll probably add a `SupervisorComment` table and `HumanResourcesComment` table and ...

Comment: It will make your project unmaintainable at some point if you just continue adding tables which essentially contain the same and it violates an aspect of normalization (which I admittedly don't know off the cuff).

Comment: I agree with the solution of BigMike, with relation tables. But there you have the same problem and it's not so intuitive. Maybe the best solution would to have a table with two fields (id field as primary key and varchar field as category or something like that). And in your comments table you add a new field (categoryId as foreign key). so you can work with 2 tables + X category tables (Employee, Job, ..).

Comment: Adding relations tables with just IDs is not a big hassle, they're used just for joins and read always with the driving table, thus leaving correlations logic (joins) to my data layer. Quickness of access (for viewing or reporting) may be obtained via Views. However having a Comment_Types table may be a good solution, but it will imply a 3-table join (and this can lead to bottlenecks).

Answer (score 0):

I personally would just add a comment column to each table, and string variable to each class.

In your database if you wanted to have the comments in a seperate table I think you would need two seperate tables which seems a bit pointless for the data which is being stored. You would need the two tables because the IDs of each could conflict if you keep the comments for both Job and Employee in one table.

In the software what do you do to comments other than get / set the value that would warrant having this in a seperate class? It seems like using an extra class for the comments would just overcomplicate things.

Comment: That would only let you store a single comment per Employee or JOb

Comment: That is true, but it wasnt mentioned that multiple comments would be needed. If not then my solution saves 3 tables, however if multiple comments are needed I would agree with Chris or Felix about using two seperate tables

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep in one table:

```
Comment:
JobCommented : int <- references a job
EmployeeCommented : int <- references an employee
Comment : string
```

Both JobCommented and EmployeeCommented are nullable. Whichever is filled connects to the parent.

Comment: It would work but it makes [Boyce and Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) sad.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a comment table

```
commentId NUMBER;
commentText VARCHAR2;
```

and two relation tables:

EmployeeComments

```
commentId NUMBER;
employeeId NUMBER;
```

and JobsComments

```
commentId NUMBER;
jobId NUMBER;
```

then select comments with inner joins.

This should respect at least first three forms of db normalization.

PS: of course there'd be some Foreign Keys just to be sure to don't forget orphaned comments.

For the objects in c#, well, just read with a left join the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create a single class `Comments` and have a `List` of them in each of your existing classes. If there are any variations then you can always subclass into JobComments and EmployeeComments.

For the database I would probably actually keep the two tables separate. This is in part because I think that it will probably be easier to do so in terms of worrying about identities. If they are in the same table as each other then you'd need to worry about a compund key of ParentTable and ParentId or similar.

Also if the two comment types ever diverge then it will be much easier to have them in separate tables in the database.